# Collecting IDs from MYSQL DB , saving particular formate in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am working on a application, where i need to find the IDs for table using query `select id from users` and save in DB with format of 1:2:3:4:5:6... and so on.

What i done so far, I can extract the IDs , However i am not able to put it into the above format.

Once I successfully store the above format in Db then I am planning to use `explode(delimiter, string)`  for splitting the format and storing it in array. Issue with explode is its store one value in one variable.

Followings things, I've tried :

```
Select ID from users;
```

Storing the above IDs

```
$idarr . = $row['id'];
$outputarr = explode(':',$idarr);
```

Can you please suggest me solution ?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and where you're having trouble, and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$val='';
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
foreach($array as $key){
$val .= $key.':'    ;
}
echo $val;
?>
```

This is an example code...Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Store each id in array then use implode like

```
$arr = implode(":",$idArray);
```

then Store`$arr` variable to your database

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the IDs from mysql db and iterate over a list of IDs and put the IDs in a string and save it to the DB.